# C# easy way to add keys and values to nested dictionary?

Tags: c#, dictionary

Is there an easy way to add value to a nested dictionary. I am looking for a way to replace the following type of code with an easy one.

```
if (NestedDictionary.ContainsKey(key1))
{
    if (NestedDictionary[key1].ContainsKey(key2))
    {
        if (NestedDictionary[key1][key2].ContainsKey(key3))
        {   
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            NestedDictionary[key1][key2].Add(key3,1);

        }
    }
    else
    {

        NestedDictionary[key1].Add(key2, new Dictionary<int,int>() { { key3, 1 } });
    }
}
else
{
    NestedDictionary.Add(key1, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,int>>() { { key2, new Dictionary<int,int>() { { key3, 1} } } });
}
```

Comment: Looks to me like you need a more well defined object to mange that data...

Comment: Programmers sometimes write classes.

Comment: Isn't it the same as Dictionary with key1,key2,key3 combination?

Comment: As stated above: Write a class instead of using nested dicts, and also: use TryGetValue rather than using ContainsKey to avoid double lookups

Comment: @Stilgar How do you know this isn't a class that represents a data structure as a three-tiered dictionary?

Comment: I don't but seems like it can be broken further into even more classes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can write a `GetOrAdd` method that either gets the value for a particular key if it's there, or assigns a new value if there is none:

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key,
    TValue newValue)
{
    TValue oldValue;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
        return oldValue;
    else
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

(Note you can create a second overload that accepts a `Func<TValue>` instead of a `TValue`, which is useful if the value is either expensive to create or causes side effects.)

Now this problem becomes very easy:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>();
dictionary.GetOrAdd(key1, new Dictionary<int, string>())[key2] = value;
```

We get the inner dictionary for the outer key, or create a new blank one if it doesn't exist, and then we assign the new value to the dictionary returned.  Note that the indexer will add an item if it doesn't exist or update the item if it already does.

This of course scales reasonably well as we add dimensions as well:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>>();
dictionary.GetOrAdd(key1, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, string>>())
    .GetOrAdd(key2, new Dictionary<int, string>())[key3] = value;
```

In our case we are actually fine always adding the default value of `TValue` using our `GetOrAdd` method, so if we add an overload to support that:

```
public static TValue GetOrAdd<TKey, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary,
    TKey key)
    where TValue : new()
{
    TValue oldValue;
    if (dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out oldValue))
        return oldValue;
    else
    {
        var newValue = new TValue();
        dictionary.Add(key, newValue);
        return newValue;
    }
}
```

It simplifies the code even more:

```
dictionary.GetOrAdd(key1).GetOrAdd(key2)[key3] = value;
```

And if you really end up doing this particular operation a *lot*, you can just create a method to do the whole thing:

```
public static void AddMany<TKey1, TKey2, TKey3, TValue>(
    this Dictionary<TKey1, Dictionary<TKey2, Dictionary<TKey3, TValue>>> dictionary,
    TKey1 key1,
    TKey2 key2,
    TKey3 key3,
    TValue newValue)
{
    dictionary.GetOrAdd(key1).GetOrAdd(key2)[key3] = newValue;
}
```

Allowing you to write:

```
dictionary.AddMany(key1, key2, key3, value);
```

Of course, you need to create a new `AddMany` overload for each number of keys you want to support, and it has to be a number known at compile time, but that does appear to be the case in your example.

Comment: I write a lot of parser code where a situation arises which does not allow to have more than 1 of a combinations of variables. I use those as keys. Is it possible to create something with method(params object[] arg) where the method will detect the param number and type and they do GetOrAdd. Last param will be value.

Comment: @YousufHossain No as you wouldn't be able to know the type of any of the dictionaries; to know the dictionary's type you'd need to know how deep it goes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the inner part:

```
if (NestedDictionary.ContainsKey(key1))
{
    if (NestedDictionary[key1].ContainsKey(key2))
    {
       NestedDictionary[key1][key2][key3]=1;
    }
    else
    {
        NestedDictionary[key1].Add(key2, new Dictionary<int,int>() { { key3, 1 } });
    }
}
else
{
    NestedDictionary.Add(key1, new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int,int>>() { { key2, new Dictionary<int,int>() { { key3, 1} } } });
}
```

But that's about it.

But what's the point of the structure?  You only ever add a constant value (1) to the innermost dictionary, so there's no real "value" there.  You might as well use a `List<string>` at that level.